# Android Safe Mode Password Protection

Tags: android, locking, safe-mode

I found MMGuardian a pretty App to Monitor Android devices. It includes a Feature called Safe Mode Lock (http://www.mmguardian.com/safe-mode-lock). Which protects Safe Mode booting with a Password. Has somebody a idea how it works, how I can implement a similar Feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a easy solution.

The idea is simple. On shutdown the device password will be set to a master password. The normal user doesn't know the password. And on boot the password will be reset to teh users password, but the reset will not be executed in Safe Mode. So the safe mode is locked for normal users. I'm not sure if it's works for all devices,

You can find the source at github https://github.com/areman/samo

Comment: Yes.. This works on MOST devices.... I have been using this for safe mode blocking since very long.. I'm surprised (happy) to see someone come out with the same solution I believed only I have thought of !!!